# How to get the stemming highlights in Mark.JS?

Tags: javascript, php, sphinx

I have working pieces of code:

PHP:

```
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=ubuntu;port=9306;charset=utf8','','');
$query = $conn->quote($_GET['query']);
 $sql = "SELECT *,SNIPPET(content,$query) AS `snippet` FROM `test1` WHERE  MATCH($query)";

foreach ($conn->query($sql) as $info) {
     echo $info['snippet']. "<br><br>";
}

$_SESSION['phrase'] = $query; // Only 1 word here now (or phrase with space), while need in array.
```

and JS:

```
markInstance = new Mark(textCont);
markInstance.mark(phrase, {}); // from $_SESSION['phrase']
highlighted = [...textCont.querySelectorAll('mark')];
positions = highlighted.map(el => el.offsetTop);
```

I have a few different highlighted words in snippet output (stemming). But only one from them highlights by [Mark.JS](https://jsfiddle.net/julmot/hdyLpy37/).

I want to use all founded stems as highlighted words in html file too.  How I could use stemming result from Sphinx in Mark.js ?

Comment: Dont see how can pass the 'stemming' rules from Sphinx to mark.js. Sphinx has the rules hard coded in code, which could recreate in JS. But if you have the highlighted snippet from sphinx, why do even need Mark.js - seems like doing same thing (just differently)

Comment: @Barryhunter ! I no need in stemming rules, but only in result. I enter phrase and get snippet from Sphinx (thanks to You).  Also I add links to html  on that page. If user click the links then open html file with full text, where Mark.JS make highlighting. My problem is that Mark.JS get only one phrase (and possible there not sharp phrase in that html)

Comment: You can see it here:  [link](http://94.180.154.148/?query=access#)     Of course direct thumb solution is delete one by one symbols from end phrase in JS while there be equal phrase in html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, so you need to implement stemming support in Mark.js somehow. Maybe with something like
https://github.com/MarkKahn/stem as inspiration

... uses a lot of regular expressions so perhaps can implment them as regula expression highlighting in mark.js.

(forget that the stemming capablity in sphinx as such, not sure its any direct use (other than to imply its POSSIBLE to implement). You can't use sphinxes engine within mark.js directly)

Comment: How I could get bold words from snippet output? (simple solution) Microsoft <b>Access</b>

Comment: I meant it is possible enough for me to get all bolded words from one snippets on html page and add it to array. Then transfer array to funcion.js use Mark.JS.

Comment: Ah, ok, suppost that might work. Would need to 'parse' the HTML snippet returned from sphinx and extract the words (eg using `preg_match_all()`) - although there are lots of options on how snippet is built http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#api-func-buildexcerpts - could maniupate that to get an 'easier to parse' snippet from sphinx.

Comment: if careful might even be able to make snippet produce almost runnable code, eg `before_match="'", after_match="'", chunk_separator=", ",around=0, query_mode=true, force_all_words=true,allow_empty=true`

Comment: preg_match_all('/<b>(.+?)<\/b>/', $info['snippet'], $matches );
$stem = array_intersect_key($matches[0], array_unique(array_map('strtolower', $matches[0])));
$_SESSION['stemming'][$id] = $stem;

Comment: so I get nice:   Array
(
    [398] => Array
        (
            [0] => stopping
            [2] => stop
        )

    [60] => Array
        (
            [0] => stop
        )

    [244] => Array
        (
            [0] => stop
        )

    [574] => Array
        (
            [0] => Stop
        )

    [92] => Array
        (
            [0] => stopped
        )

Comment: and I get it in JS and Mark.JS worked!  $phrase = implode(" ", $_SESSION['stemming'][$_GET['id']]); Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Interesting that need use $matches[1] not $matches[0], because $matches[0] contents bold words and it don't work in Mark.JS (minus 3 hours from my sleep)

Comment: Yes, $m[0] contains the 'whole' matched string - including the b tags etc. $m[1] (and $m[2] etc) would contain the 'parameterized' matches (in brackets/perentesis)

Comment: Dear Barryhunter! I finished my prog with Your help. Did You open  [link](http://94.180.154.148/)  ? I would wanted send to You full sources by e-mail